# Load RTF into Winforms Richtextbox "in stages"

Tags: winforms, powershell, richtextbox, rtf

I need to display a large (>8000 lines) RTF-formatted text in my **Winforms RichTextBox**. But while texts up to ~500 lines appear instantly in the RichTextBox, a large text like this **takes a couple of minutes**.

So I was thinking, is there any way to load the Richtext **in smaller portions** into the RichTextBox, i.e. only when the user is scrolling further down?

Unfortunately the most obvious candidate, the method `appendtext()` only works for plain text, not rich text.
Switching to WPF is currently not an option unfortunately.

Thanks!

Comment: Try hiding the RTB first, load it and then show it. This generally helps improve performance. It wont render in "live" mode when the control is being displayed.

Comment: Thanks, but i already do that. Does not help much performance wise, unfortunately.

Comment: try to separate the data to groups of 50 lines for example, then add event handler for keydown to add another 50 see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745817(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The Problem is not how to handle keyboard-events and splitting the text. The problem is that there is no way (that i know of) to APPEND richtext in a RichTextBox.

Comment: of course there is: `$richtextbox1.AppendText("Text")`

Comment: I'm sorry but did you even read my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer finally: one needs to make a selection at the very end of the RTF in the Richtextbox and the paste the next portion like this: `$RichTextBox1.SelectedRtf = $rtf`. 
Loading the RTF in portions of about 600 lines, this is way faster (about 10x) than loading the whole RTF at once. Still much, much slower than loading plain text of the same size, though.